# What's best practice for updating arbitrarily nested object state in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, json, tree, state

Given an arbitrarily deep object structure, nested nodes and child nodes:

{Node
ID
[{Node, ID, [{node, id... Etc}]}]
}

How best to manage ReactJS state and add new nodes into the structure?

I can display the tree view of these nodes easily enough - recurse through each node and display in a component that in turn loops through the children and display in a new instance of the component... And so on.

But how do I then update a nested array of nodes such that it updates state at the higher level?

I can't quite see my way through the problem...

Could pass the whole state tree down to each display component, but it still isn't clear how to address a specific point in that state tree in which to add a new node... And have that state updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [Object destructuring and Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Here is an example on how to update a prop value in an object state:

```
export default function MyApp() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@example.com'
  });

  function handleFirstNameChange(e) {
    setPerson(oldPerson => ({
      ...oldPerson,
      firstName: e.target.value
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, had thought about destructuring, but getting caught up in that the change could be arbitrarily deep in the structure.